# NodeJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token for operation

Tags: node.js

When trying to run a lowdb example from https://github.com/typicode/lowdb I got the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token for operation '||='
```

It fails in the line:

```
db.data ||= { posts: [] }
```

I am using nodejs 14.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using nodejs 14.

The logical assignment `||=` is not supported in Node.js 14. It's supported starting 15.0.0

See [Node.green](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment).

Comment: Support starts with version 15.0.0 - just verified myself to be certain!

Comment: @Gershy you're right. The table was combining 15.0.0 - 15.14.0 results which misled me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [or assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) supported from node version 15.0.0+. All you need to do is upgrade to version 15.0.0!